# Re: finding repeating patterns with lines in between

Tags: python, regex

The input is as follows

```
MY_PROJ10  
1st line  
2nd line  

MY_PROJ11  
3rd line  
4th line  


----------
```

Using Regular expressions I want to capture

```
result [0]  
Group 0 MY_PROJ10  
Group 1  
1st line  
2nd line

result [1]  
Group 0 MY_PROJ11  
Group 1  
3rd line  
4th line
```

My first crack at this is
regex = *r"^(MY_PROJ.+)([\s\S]+)"*
and then doing multi line
But this captures the all the following lines after **MY_PROJ10**
I am sure there way to do this in regular expressions.
I am trying with regex101.com but not luck as of yet

Comment: Use [`(?m)^(MY_PROJ.*)((?:\n(?!MY_PROJ\d).*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/n3zEFY/2).

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`(?m)^(MY_PROJ.*)([\s\S]*?)(?=[\n\r]MY_PROJ|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/n3zEFY/1):

```
    In [2]: s = """
   ...: MY_PROJ10
   ...: 1st line
   ...: 2nd line
   ...:
   ...: MY_PROJ11
   ...: 3rd line
   ...: 4th line
   ...: """

In [3]: re.findall(r'(?m)^(MY_PROJ.*)([\s\S]*?)(?=[\n\r]MY_PROJ|\Z)', s)
Out[3]:
[('MY_PROJ10', '\n1st line  \n2nd line  \n'),
 ('MY_PROJ11', '\n3rd line  \n4th line\n')]
```

Comment: thing of beauty and it works Chrisz. Now how do you learn these kind of tricky ones ? Any advice (other than posting in SO :) )

Comment: This is a good starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: Also, for any regular expressions where you want to match *until* something, positive lookahead is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
(?s)(MY_PROJ\d+)[\s]*((?:(?!MY_PROJ\d+).)+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/131)